# EXPLAIN PLAN: what is the difference between "using where" and "using index" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

What is the major difference between 'uing where' and 'using index' in EXPLAIN plan of MYSQL.

I think this is just the searching for the records from disc vs searching from memory respectively.

Thanks,
-UDAY

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) explains the difference:

- `Using index` means the requested column data can be fetched from the index only, without having to read the row data proper.
- `Using where` means the index is actually used for lookups, instead of only for fetching the requested column data.